# Accessing two apps in one view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django project with two apps. The first one, `market/models.py`, includes a Market class and a Share class, where the latter keeps track of all shares bought or sold on any given market, as follows:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    shares_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Share(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user_shares', 
        default=None)
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        Market, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='market_shares', 
        default=None)
    share = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.share)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_list')
```

The second app, `user/models.py`, is to create custom users, as follows:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
```

**What I want to do is this**: on clicking a button on a template for a specific market, the code will loop through all users with shares in that market to add/subtract the value of each share in their possession from their total points (subtraction would happen when users own negative shares, meaning they owe shares on account of short-selling). The value of each share at that point is simply the current market price.

Here is what I have at the moment, in `markets/views.py` (the `HttpResponseRedirect` at the end simply reloads the page):

```
def resolve(request, pk):
    market = Market.objects.get(pk=pk)
    market_users = Share.objects.values('user')
    for user in market_users:
        target_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
        target_user.points += market.current_price * int(user.share)
    market.open = False
    market.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + str(pk))
```

One problem with this (there might be others) is that target_user ends up being of the form `<QuerySet [{'user': 1}, {'user': 1}]>`, which means Django throws the error `CustomUser matching query does not exist`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE following Higor's suggestion in the comments:**

I tried this, which doesn't throw an error, but it fails to update users points:

```
def resolve(request, pk):
    market = Market.objects.get(pk=pk)
    market_users = Share.objects.all() 
    print(market_users) # gives "<QuerySet [<Share: 10>, <Share: 10>]>"
    for user in market_users.iterator():
        print(user) # gives "10 10"
        if user.market == pk:
            target_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
            target_user.points += market.current_price * user.share
            target_user.save()
    market.open = False
    market.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + str(pk))
```

Comment: That's because you're using `.values('user')` which returns a dictionary. You could use a normal queryset for that and loop over `qs.iterator()` for performance.

Comment: Thanks @HigorRossato! See edit in the post. Let me know if I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: that's correct. What's the outcome of that?

Comment: @HigorRossato, see further edits to post: seems the issue is that the query set gives shares, not users. What I'm trying to loop/iterate over is of course the latter, so that I can look for matches between the Share and the CustomUser models, in order to update the points of users in the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is the way you access your `user` inside your `Share` object.

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def resolve(request, pk):
    # if no Market with this pk raises a 404
    market = get_object_or_404(Market, pk=pk)
    # get shares for the specific market
    shares = Share.objects.filter(market_id=pk).select_related('user')
    print(shares) # gives "<QuerySet [<Share: 10>, <Share: 10>]>"
    for share in shares:
        target_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=share.user.pk)
        target_user.points += market.current_price * share.share
        target_user.save()
    market.open = False
    market.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + str(pk))
```

Instead of hardcode your URL you can use reverse like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#examples)

Comment: Thanks for this, Higor! The problem is that 'market' isn't a feature of CustomUser (only points is) so this throws an error, I'm afraid: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'market'

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've changed/edited a bit as well. Please, try that to see if works.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for all of your help, @HigorRossato! I really appreciate it.